# Material Alert Dialog, The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make a  MaterialAlertDialog but I keep getting the following error no matter what

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:213)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialDialogs.getDialogBackgroundInsets(MaterialDialogs.java:60)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.<init>(MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.java:117)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.<init>(MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.java:103)
        at com.adamm.quem.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:118)
```

I am using a custom theme as my MainActivity theme which is a parent of MaterialComponents

```
<style name="MainMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Changing the theme to AppCompat doesn't help and isn't really right to do
I am following the implementation as Material IO explains https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialog/

My code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setTitle("Title")
                            .setMessage("Message")
                    builder.show();
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're passing in `getApplicationContext()` and the application context doesn't have your theme. Pass in your activity as the context:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("Message")
builder.show();
```

Comment: Could you please explain? what is the difference between both, and how can I make my context have the theme? as I need to use AlertDialog in a RecyclerView.ViewHolder, how can I get such context?

Comment: Thanks, I created a static context variable that is initiated in MainActivity with MainActivity.this reference, managed to get it working in ViewHolder

Comment: Don't ever store a static reference to a Context as that will most definitely be a source of memory leaks. Just pass your Activity as a constructor parameter when constructing your adapter / ViewHolder

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution:

```
val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this@MainActivity)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
```